# Как получить все блоки?

Tags: jquery

Есть разметка вида:

```
<div id="block">
    <div class="sample">html code</div>
    <div class="sample">html code</div>
    <div class="sample">html code</div>
    <div class="sample">html code</div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно получить все блоки **sample** чтобы в дальнейшем я мог обработать каждый. Что-то вроде перебора массива.

Делаю так:

```
$('#block .sample').html();
```

Но так я получаю только первый блок.

Как пройтись по всем? (что-то типа foreach в php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery**

```js
$('.sample').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
  <div class="sample">html code1</div>
  <div class="sample">html code2</div>
  <div class="sample">html code3</div>
  <div class="sample">html code4</div>
</div>
```

**vanilla javascript:**

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.sample')].forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div id="block">
    <div class="sample">html code1</div>
    <div class="sample">html code2</div>
    <div class="sample">html code3</div>
    <div class="sample">html code4</div>
</div>
```